# Ruby on Rails: Best way to add gems at project initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Every month or so I have to create a Rails project at work.

The procedure is always the same...

Run `rails new [...]` & edit the Gemfile.

I have about 12 gems I always add on any project no matter what kind of project that is. Most of them are development gems, some of them production gems.

The gems range from ActiveAdmin to BetterErrors and so on. Problem is: I always have to remember which gems I use on a regular basis and run the same procedure everytime I start a project:

```
Open google.com
Search for the correct names of the gems
Add the gems to the Gemfile accordingly
Repeat til I'm satisfied with my Gemfile
```

I wish I could do something like this: `rails new Project --use-my-gems`

I know it's possible somehow using a text-file to store my most used gems (or a Gemfile itself and overwrite the default Gemfile with my).

Basically I want multiple Rails Gemtemplates which  can be switched at project initialization by passing an argument to `rails`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Rails Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html).

You can specify your gems in the template:

```
gem "bj"
gem "nokogiri"
```

... with a lot of other options.

Then start your new app with:

```
rails new app -m ~/template.rb
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you. :)